# Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)

Tags: macos, applescript, security, error, automation

I can execute my Apple Script when I load/open it from Apple Script Editor. No errors. However, I have added Editor to the menu bar of my Mac (Catalina OS) with my script copied to the User Scripts Folder so I can execute it directly from the menu bar. But I can't seem to understand why I get the error:

```
Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)
```

Any ideas as to why it works when executing from Editor but fails with this error when executed from menu bar? Below is a copy of my script just for reference.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "iTerm2"
        keystroke "/usr/local/bin/python3 $HOME/Rosie.py"
        key code 36
    end tell
    
end tell
```

Here is the script in the menu bar. I have already added and removed the script under Privacy settings all to no avail.

[image]