# osascript "authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)" when invoked via JumpCloud

Tags: terminal, applescript, monterey

I have cooked up a JumpCloud Command to automate the configuration of desktop backgrounds. I can get the command to run on a test system (Monterey, 12.4) via Shell if I approve a dialog asking for permission. When I execute via JumpCloud, I get:

```
59:74: execution error: Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)
```

The command itself:

```
target_user=$(w | awk '$2 == "console"{print $1}')
export target_user
sudo -u $target_user osascript<<__OSA
tell application "System Events"
 tell every desktop
  set pictures folder to "/Users/$target_user/Documents/Desktop_Images"
  set picture rotation to 2 -- using interval
  set change interval to 1800
 end tell
end tell
__OSA
```

I see a similar unanswered question here: [Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436615/not-authorized-to-send-apple-events-to-system-events-1743)

I have found solutions that suggest looking in "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation" but there are no apps listed under "Automation." Under "Full Disk Access" there's a check for "jumpcloud-agent" ... perhaps I can extend that somehow?

Comment: If you select one of the items on the left pane, such as "Location Services" or "Accessibility", did you try scrolling down or arrowing down to find "Automation"? It is there for me on 12.4.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I got fooled by the invisible scroll bar! :D